# how can i SendMessage Tab & UP Arrow Send to winform? C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Program
{
    //include FindWindowEx
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

    //include SendMessage
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    //this is a constant indicating the window that we want to send a text message
    const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //getting notepad's process | at least one instance of notepad must be running
        Process notepadProccess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Codns3")[0];

        //getting notepad's textbox handle from the main window's handle
        //the textbox is called 'Edit'
        IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);//창핸들
        IntPtr codnsButton = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "#32770", null);//창핸들
        //sending the message to the textbox 0x26
        //SendMessage(codnsButton, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x26, 0x26);
        //SendMessage(codnsButton, WM_KEYUP, 0x26, 0x26);
        SendMessage((System.IntPtr)00430350, 0021, 00430350, 02010001);
        SendMessage(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "172846200035");
    }
}
```

When actually passing a string, it is passed to the edit class.
Before that, after the program starts `uparrow -> enter -> string to edit class`
Like this.
But currently the uparrow and enter keys are not being passed.
What is the problem? I attach my code.

Comment: `IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);`

Comment: @GSerg .. Not works. but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when running the program, there are two check boxes for the first form, among which the check is selected at the bottom. Here, if you click the up arrow after clicking the program window, the checkbox button moves from the bottom to the top.

After that, press Enter and the second form will appear. After tapping the tab twice on the second form, enter the desired number
You need to log in by pressing Enter again.

You should try this process by rebooting your computer every day.
What I found through google ring is to enter the desired number
This skips the first form by myself and executes the source I found in the second form, and it is entered in the first textbox.
So all I need to do is press the tab key and the arrow keys above the arrow keys.

You have to figure out how.
What I can do right now is that I can enter numbers, simple letters, etc. into the first focus textbox.